# How do I get analytics data from Playable ADS?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have added gtag to my playable ads app (javascript, single html). This works by direct link, but does not work for advertising platforms. I do not receive data (events) if the playable is launched through Unity, Applovine, Ironsource, etc. (These advertising platforms must support gtag).
What could be the problem?
Thanks.

I created a data stream, created special events, and added a default script.Next, I'm calling an event like: `gtag("event", "eventName");`

I think the problem is that the advertising platforms launch the Playable in the Iframe.